# How can I launch notepad with psexec when logged in via SSH?

Tags: psexec

As I understand it, I should be able to launch notepad with psexec when logged in via SSH.

```
psexec c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

All I see is this

```
PsExec v2.43 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2023 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

.. and then it just hangs there, as if it's open, but I don't see it on the desktop.

Is this supposed to work like this?

What protocol does psexec use? Is it over SMB?